# Functions of a Complex Variable and Complex Differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I prove that complex differentiability of $f$ at a point $z$ together with the condition $f'(z)\neq 0$ is equivalent to being a conformal map at $z$?

I know that a map $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ conformal at every point $z \in D$ is said to be conformal in $D$. It is realized by a holomorphic function in $z$ with no critical points ($f'(z)\neq 0$). Is this enough to prove the statement above? What do I need to show that complex differentiability of $f$ at a point $z$ together with the condition $f'(z)\neq 0$ is equivalent to being a conformal map at $z$?

Comment: Did you mean $f'(z)\neq0$?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer, thanks for correcting me. I just made the necessary corrections.